# How can I wrap a vue component during cypress component testing?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I am using [component testing in Cypress on Vue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/tree/develop/npm/vue).  My project components use the [vuetify plugin](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#webpack-install).

Currently, tested components load with Vuetify:

```js
import DebuggingTemporaryComponent from "./DebuggingTemporaryComponent";
import {mount} from "@cypress/vue";
import vuetify from '../../resources/js/vuetify'

it('mounts the component with vuetify', () => {
    
    mount(DebuggingTemporaryComponent,{vuetify,})

    cy.contains('Hello World') ✅

}
```

However, the stylings are not functioning correctly because Vuetify components need to be wrapped in a `<v-app>` at least once on the page.  In component testing this is not happening.

I need to customise the wrapper as suggested [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/14672#issuecomment-900825353) in the docs for the React equivalent.  However whenever I try to make my own function to do this, I get an error that the appropriate webpack loader isn't there.  Vue loader is there and working.

```js
import {mount as cypressMount} from '@cypress/vue'

export function mount (component){
    return cypressMount(<v-app>component</v-app>, prepareComponent(props, options))
}
```

Can anyone help me with where to go next with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can construct a simple wrapper in the test, for example

**Component to test - Button.vue**

```html
<template>
  <v-btn color="red lighten-2" dark>
    Click Me
  </v-btn>
</template>
```

**Test**

```js
import Button from "./Button";
import {mount} from "@cypress/vue";
import vuetify from '../plugins/vuetify'
import { VApp } from 'vuetify/lib/components'

const WrapperComp = {
  template: `
    <v-app>
      <Button />
    </v-app>
  `,
  components: {
    VApp,
    Button
  }
}

it('mounts the component with vuetify', () => {

  mount(WrapperComp, { vuetify })

  const lightRed = 'rgb(229, 115, 115)'
  cy.contains('button', 'Click Me')        // ✅
    .should('have.css', 'background-color', lightRed)  // fails if no <v-app> used above
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You get an error because you are trying to use JSX which is indeed [possible with Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#JSX) but you need to configure additional build plugins.

Same can be achieved without JSX by using [render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html)

```js
import {mount} from "@cypress/vue";
import vuetify from '../../resources/js/vuetify'
import { VApp } from 'vuetify/lib/components'

function mountComponentWithVuetify(componentToMount, options = {}) 
{
  return mount({
    render(h) {
      return h(VApp, [h(componentToMount)])
    }
  },
  { 
    vuetify, 
    ...options,
  })
}
```